# python regular expression re.sub error

Tags: python, regex

I have a .csv files that might have brackets mixed in:

```
line = "fdf,dfdf,(1,2,3,4,5),(ss,dd),"
```

Now I want to replace all the () with "", so that it looks like this:

```
line = 'fdf,dfdf,"1,2,3,4,5","ss,dd",'
```

My code is:

```
line=re.sub(',(', ',"', line)
line=re.sub('),', '",', line)
```

However I got this error:

```
 ...
 File "/usr/local/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/local/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

What is wrong here?!!

Answer (score 4):

how bout just simple string substitution

```
print strs.replace("(",'"').replace(")",'"')
```

no need for regex for this

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think  “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 2):

`(` have special meaning in regular expressions you can escape them using `\(` or place them use square `[]` brackets.

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "fdf,dfdf,(1,2,3,4,5),(ss,dd),"
>>> re.sub(r"[()]",'"',strs)
'fdf,dfdf,"1,2,3,4,5","ss,dd",'
#or
>>> re.sub(r"\(|\)",'"',strs)
'fdf,dfdf,"1,2,3,4,5","ss,dd",'
```

Comment: +1 for showing him how to do it with regex since thats what he actually asked for ...

Answer (score 1):

another one would be to consider this..

```
import re 
re.sub('\)', '\"', re.sub('\(', '\"', line))
```

what you do is replace one pran once and then replace the other one.